# Excel - use a range of values without the zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a column of values that has a mix of positive numbers and zeros. I want to use various functions like MIN, MAX, AVERAGE, etc that calculates the result of just the nonzero numbers. Without making any changes to the data, is there a way to get functions to calculate this?

Ideally, there would be like a MINIF(range,">0") type of function. But I do not believe those exist. I would like to avoid using VBA as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an array formula like so:

```
 =MIN(IF($A$1:$A$10<>0,$A$1:$A$10))
```

Hold CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in the formula bar to make this an array formula.

You can do the same thing with the MAX and AVERAGE functions.

NOTE: Array formulas are inside { } - this is how you know you did it right.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have `Excel 2007` or later you can use `AVERAGEIF` for averaging without zero, e.g.

`=AVERAGEIF(Range,">0")`

....but for `MIN` the normal approach is an array formula as `AxGryndr` suggests, and that same approach can be used for other functions, although non-array options are available, e.g. for smallest non zero value

`=SMALL(Range,COUNTIF(Range,0)+1)`

For `MAX` you can presumably just use a regular `MAX` function because that will be the same with or without zeroes, i.e.

`=MAX(Range)`

Comment: I didn't think about that. Obviously max is max with or without zeroes. Nice catch.